# How can I use imagemagick's identify command in a script to tell if a JPEG file is invalid or corrupt?

Tags: scripting, imagemagick

I have a somewhat-kludgey script in which I want to copy valid, complete JPEG files to a photo album directory. I thought I could use ImageMagick's `identify` command to do this. The [web documentation for that command](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) says

> The identify program describes the format and characteristics of one or more image files. It also reports if an image is incomplete or corrupt.

... which sounds great. And if I run `identify jpeg:testfile.jpg`, I get an exit code of `0` if the test file is a JPEG, and `1` if it isn't. Good start — but the command also returns `0` if the file appears to be a JPEG but is incomplete.
I looked through the extensive list of options, but nothing seems relevant. Can I use this command to do what I want? How?

Comment: Have you tried with `-regard-warnings`? "It also causes IM to return a proper exit status according to such error conditions." http://hoernle1.de/m/imagick6/basics/index.html#regard-warnings

Comment: @jasonwryan: Wow, that's significantly more descriptive than the text from imagemagick.org, which just says (in entirety) "Pay attention to warning messages." The version on my CentOS 5-based server is missing that option, but I tried it on a Fedora box, and it seems to return success even on severely truncated images.

Comment: I can get it to exit with the correct code if the image is corrupt (by redirecting shredded bytes to a `.jpg`), but I don't have a truncated file to test on. Sorry: that's all I've got.

Comment: It's easy to make a truncated copy with `dd`....

Comment: OK: `dd`'ed a `.jpg` and it accurately reports it corrupted if I overwrite the start of the file (header etc), but reports it as good if I truncate it. Bug?

Comment: Or maybe just overly-optimistic documentation. I guess I should bring this up on an imagemagick mailing list. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If an alternate program is an option, I think I used [`jpeginfo -c`](http://www.kokkonen.net/tjko/projects.html) the last time I needed to check the validity of a bunch of JPEG files.

Comment: `jpeginfo`'s output shows tags like: [ERROR] [WARNING] or [OK], Here is a sample message: `... 37768  Premature end of JPEG file  [WARNING]`... In this case, 37768 is the file length in bytes.... Howerver, `identify` did not report a warning for this particular file, and yet some image viewers won't display it, so `jpeginfo` seems to do a better job